# Dealing with SMTP invalid command attack

Tags: linux, security, smtp, sendmail

One of our semi-busy mail servers (sendmail) has had a lot of inbound connections over the past few days from hosts that are issuing garbage commands.

In the past two days:

- incoming smtp connections with invalid commands from 39,000 unique IPs
- the IPs come from various ranges all over the world, not just a few networks that I can block
- the mail server serves users throughout north america, so I can't just block connections from unknown IPs
- sample bad commands:  http://pastebin.com/4QUsaTXT

I am not sure what someone is trying to accomplish with this attack, besides annoy me.

any ideas what this is about, or how to effectively deal with it?

Comment: As this traffic has nothing to do with smtp, i wonder if some layer 7 firewall could drop it before it reaches sendmail.

Answer (score 4):

Here is at least one option for tarpitting these connections after they start spitting out errors. Valid and well-behaved clients shouldn't ever fall into this tarpit.

```
dnl # New option in v8.14.0
dnl # Override default limit (of 20) NOOPs (invalid or unsupported SMTP
dnl #   commands) before daemon will throttle connection by slowing
dnl #   error message replies (similar to "confBAD_RCPT_THROTTLE")
define(`MaxNOOPCommands', `5')dnl
```

You can also use the GreetPause feature, which will reject these clients because they are unlikely to respect the pause. You can read more about it here: http://www.deer-run.com/~hal/sysadmin/greet_pause.html

```
dnl # New feature in v8.13.1 (not listed in Companion)
dnl # Set time in milliseconds before sendmail will present its banner
dnl #   to a remote host (spammers won't wait and will already be
dnl #   transmitting before pause expires, and sendmail will
dnl #   refuse based on pre-greeting traffic) 5000=5 seconds
dnl # NOTE: Requires use of FEATURE(`access_db') and "GreetPause" entries
dnl #       in access table
FEATURE(`greet_pause',`5000')dnl
```

Answer (score 1):

I would install [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/) and block at he first invalid command.